# SQL Server Profiler Not Capturing EF Queries

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

I am trying run SQL Server Profiler to view queries generated from an Entity Framework web app. I have selected every trace option in the settings but still no luck.  It does show SQL:BatchCompleted messages, but it does not show the actual query that was run.  Here is a profiler capture of a web page that loads an executes several Entity Framework queries.

[image]

The EF queries are simple like:
var file = context.Files.Find(2);

Any ideas whats going on here?  Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing mysterious about how EF connects to SQL.  RPC / Batch events _will_ capture your EF queries.  You've probably got something misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, my app was hitting the wrong database.  What was odd though is the trace for the wrong database still showed activity while running the app on my local box.